# pair up two rows in single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this table:

```
A   B          C
1   Record 1   Type 1
2   Record 2   Type 2
3   Record 3   Type 1
4   Record 4   Type 2
```

I need to pair up rows by their values in `C` (Type 1 & Type 2) given that the first record with `Type 1` must match with the nearest `ID` that with `Type 2`

Desired output:

```
A   B         C        A   B         C
1   Record 1  Type 1   2   Record 2  Type 2
3   Record 3  Type 1   4   Record 4  Type 2
```

I tried doing this in a query with 2 CTEs but I couldnt come up with the expected result:

```
WITH SET_A (A, B, C) AS

    (SELECT * FROM A WHERE C = 'Type 1'),

SET_B (A, B, C) AS
    (SELECT * FROM A WHERE C = 'Type 2')

SELECT * FROM SET_A CROSS JOIN SET_B;
```

Are there any other approach than using cross joins?

Comment: it is not clear what you are trying to join on in the example.

Comment: @Randy I'm trying to pair rows such that in one row, there will be `Type 1` and `Type 2` records

Comment: Is it always 2 adjacent rows? Could you join the odds with the evens?

Comment: also - 'nearest id' - do you mean the next largest id with the opposite type?

Comment: @Randy yes exactly like that

Comment: (**1**) What exactly do you mean by "*the nearest `ID`*"? (**2**) What should happen if the number of `Type1 rows is different from the number of `Type2` rows?

Comment: @PM77-1 for (1), I want to get a `Type 2` record whose `ID` is nearest to the `ID` of the current `Type 1`. For (2), I might have to set default values if `Type 1` can't be matched with any more `Type 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. For each "Type 1" it will find the nearest subsequent (by id) "Type 2".

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a5263/20

```
CREATE TABLE t 
(
  A int,
  B varchar(32),
  C varchar(32)
  );



insert into t values (1, 'Record 1', 'Type 1')
insert into t values (2, 'Record 2', 'Type 2')
insert into t values (3, 'Record 3', 'Type 1')
insert into t values (4, 'Record 4', 'Type 2')
insert into t values (5, 'Record 5', 'Type 1')
insert into t values (6, 'Record 6', 'Type 1a')
insert into t values (7, 'Record 7', 'Type 2')


;

with set_a as 
(
  select * from t where c = 'type 1'
)
, set_b as 
(
  select a, b, c, a_match = (select max(t2.a) from t t2 where t2.a < t.a and t2.c = 'type 1') 
  from t where c = 'type 2'
)
select set_a.* , a2 = set_b.a, b2 = set_b.b, c2 = set_b.c
from set_a
join set_b on set_b.a_match = set_a.a
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.a a1, t1.b b1, t1.c c1, t2.a a2, t2.b b2, t2.c c2
FROM Table1 t1 
JOIN Table1 t2 ON t1.c = 'Type 1' AND  t2.c = 'Type 2' AND t1.a < t2.a
WHERE t2.a  = (SELECT MIN(t3.a) FROM Table1 t3 WHERE t3.c = 'Type 2' AND t3.a > t1.a)
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d62f/9)**

Comment: thanks for the answer, although your answer generated the required query, @Malk's answer suited my scenario better. I forgot to mention that Type 2 Id's cannot repeat as they can only be in one pair.
See here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0f0ff/3/0
Thanks again

Comment: I think the query is still okay, our business rules doesnt allow Type 2s before Type 1s

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable t1, yourtable t2 WHERE t1.c=t2.c
```

Comment: OP specified that he needs pairs of rows so "*there will be `Type 1` and `Type 2` records*".

Comment: Also, it's very, very, very bad idea to use `SELECT *` with `SELF JOIN`.